# PHP assigning only specific values into an incremental variable during a loop

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [column] => email
                    [value] => fskdjhfkjf@mai.com
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [column] => nickname
                    [value] => dpucci
                )

        )

    [social] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [column] => user_id
                    [value] => opweirpor
                )

        )

)
```

Starting from this array I'll have to build a string that will look like this:

```
insert(users, array(email=>fskdjhfkjf@mai.com,nickname=>dpucci)
```

And another like this:

```
insert(social, array(user_id=>opweirpor)
```

This is what I am doing:

```
foreach ($tables as $table => $queries) {
    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $insert .= $query['column'] . '=>' . $query['value'] . ',';
    }
    echo 'insert(' . $table . ', array(' . $insert . ')';
}
```

The problem is that the result I am getting is the following:

```
insert(users, array(email=>fskdjhfkjf@mai.com,nickname=>dpucci)
```

and:

```
insert(social, array(email=>fskdjhfkjf@mai.com, nickname=>dpucci, user_id=>opweirpor)
```

This is because the variable `$insert` is incremented each new loop and it is adding ALL the results instead that only the ones I need for each `$tables` loop.

How can I achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you keep appending your string to the same `$insert` in the inner loop, which is ran many times. Just clear the `insert` variable after you have finished with it, i.e. after your inner loop. (Untested)

```
foreach ($tables as $table => $queries) {
    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $insert .= $query['column'] . '=>' . $query['value'] . ',';
    }
    echo 'insert(' . $table . ', array(' . $insert . ')';

    // add this line
    $insert = "";

}
```

or, put it before the inner foreach loop, which has an advantage to ensure `$insert` is not polluted with previous codes or otherwise uninitialized giving PHP warnings.

```
foreach ($tables as $table => $queries) {

    // add this line
    $insert = "";

    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $insert .= $query['column'] . '=>' . $query['value'] . ',';
    }

    echo 'insert(' . $table . ', array(' . $insert . ')';

}
```

However, your code actually creates

```
insert(users, array(email=>fskdjhfkjf@mai.com,nickname=>dpucci,)
```

Note the comma after `dupcci`. Which I don't think is what you want. To fix this, simply remove the trailing comma with [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
foreach ($tables as $table => $queries) {

    // add this line
    $insert = "";

    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $insert .= $query['column'] . '=>' . $query['value'] . ',';
    }

    // add one more line here
    $insert = substr($insert, 0, -1);

    echo 'insert(' . $table . ', array(' . $insert . ')';

}
```

Also, check your desired output. It seems that the brackets are not balanced and the strings are unquoted. Are you sure it is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Reset the variable `$insert`.

```
foreach ($tables as $table => $queries) {
    $insert = '';
    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $insert .= $query['column'] . '=>' . $query['value'] . ',';
    }
    echo 'insert(' . $table . ', array(' . $insert . ')';
}
```